# How to change DataGridView column value based on condition

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, datagridview, ado.net

Is it possible to change the column value or cell value based on the Condition?

Consider I am having 3 columns in a `DataGridView` (i.e) to find the greatest of two number

The input from `DataGridView` is got from SQL Server.

First Datagridview column is A and second one is B and 3rd column is to find whether A is bigger than B or not. if the condition satisfies it should display the text `"TRUE"` or else `"FALSE"` in 3rd Column.

Answer (score 1):

I have answered a similar question here [Changing Cell Values of DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436858/changing-cell-values-of-datagridview/17437248#17437248)

You can use the [**`DataGridView.CellFormatting`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx) event. In your case you need to retrieve, for each Rows, the value of others Cells when the third Cell needs to be formatted.

The sample code bellow supposes:

- values are `int` in `DataGridView`: you need to do the appropriate conversion.
- no `Null`, `DbNull` Values: you need to check for null values if required.

---

```
void dgv_CellFormatting(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 2) {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(this.dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value) > Convert.ToInt32(this.dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value)) {
            e.Value = "TRUE";
        } else {
            e.Value = "FALSE";
        }
        e.FormattingApplied = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Server Side method to change the value of cell according to your condition:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Application No">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Label ID="lbl" Text='<%# chkValue(Eval("A"),Eval("B")) %>' runat="server" />
  </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

chkValue function will take two arguments and check which value is greater and return true/false accordingly.

Comment: +1 for the quick reply any way i need it for the windows Forms. i can use this for my future Purpose..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="a">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("a") %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="b">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("b") %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="display">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Convert.ToInt16(Eval("a"))>Convert.ToInt16(Eval("b"))?"True":"False" %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: +1 for the quick reply any way i need it for the windows Forms. i can use this for my future Purpose..

Answer (score 0):

```
 Protected Sub dgrd_WWWH_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles dgrd_WWWH.RowDataBound
If e.Row.RowType And DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
                Dim ColA As Label = CType(e.Row.FindControl("colA"), Label)
Dim ColB As Label = CType(e.Row.FindControl("colB"), Label)
If Val(ColA) > Val(ColB) then
dgrd_WWWH.Rows(e.Row.RowIndex).Cells(2).Text = "True"
Else
dgrd_WWWH.Rows(e.Row.RowIndex).Cells(2).Text = "False"
End If
End If
End Sub
```