# Display image inside datagridview column based on certain conditions

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am populating a `DatagGridView` using the code below:

```
using (DataTable dtLLV = new DataTable())
{
    daLLV.Fill(dtLLV);

    dgSSW.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    dgSSW.VirtualMode = true;
    dgSSW.ColumnCount = 5;

    var col0 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    {
        HeaderText = "Q. No.",
        Name = "RowNum",
        ReadOnly = true,
        Width = 70
    };
    dgSSW.Columns.Insert(0, col0);
    dgSSW.CellFormatting += GridCellFormatting;

    dgSSW.Columns[1].Name = "subsec_name";
    dgSSW.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Sub Section Name";
    dgSSW.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "subsec_name";
    dgSSW.Columns[1].Width = 210;

    dgSSW.Columns[2].Name = "rt_correct_ans";
    dgSSW.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Correct Answer";
    dgSSW.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "rt_correct_ans";

    dgSSW.Columns[3].Name = "rt_your_ans";
    dgSSW.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Your Answer";
    dgSSW.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "rt_your_ans";


    dgSSW.Columns[4].Name = "q_r_difficulty";
    dgSSW.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Difficulty Level";
    dgSSW.Columns[4].DataPropertyName = "q_r_difficulty";

    dgSSW.Columns[5].Name = "rt_quest_all_s";
    dgSSW.Columns[5].HeaderText = "qid";
    dgSSW.Columns[5].DataPropertyName = "rt_quest_all_s";
    dgSSW.Columns[5].Visible = false;

    dgSSW.DataSource = dtLLV;

    var col3 = new DataGridViewImageColumn { HeaderText = "Result", Name = "Pic",Image=imgList.Images[0] };
    dgSSW.Columns.Insert(4, col3);

    var col7 = new DataGridViewButtonColumn
    {
        HeaderText = "Action",
        Name = "Action",
        Text = "View",
        UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true
    };
    dgSSW.Columns.Add(col7);

    dgSSW.CellContentClick += GridCellContentClick;

}//data table closed and disposed here
```

Now, i want to show an image in `DataGridViewImageColumn` if the DB values of below mentioned two data bound columns are equal.How do i do these equality check in `GridCellFormatting` event?I am using C# in win forms.

> dgSSW.Columns[2].Name = "rt_correct_ans";

is equal to

> dgSSW.Columns[3].Name = "rt_your_ans";

```
Basically, here "rt_correct_ans" & "rt_your_ans" are Table fields which store Integer values like

> rt_correct_ans | rt_your_ans
--------------------------------
1              | 3
2              | 2
4              | 4
5              | 0
........

So i want to check 
if(rt_correct_ans ==  rt_your_ans)
{
  show image 1;
}
else
{
 show image 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the suggestion by @Chris [How to change DataGridView column value based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371974/how-to-change-datagridview-column-value-based-on-condition?rq=1)
I, now have modified my code in the `GridCellFormatting` event as folllows

```
if (dgSSW.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Pic")
{
    if(Convert.ToInt32(this.dgSSW.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value) == Convert.ToInt32(this.dgSSW.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value))
    {
        e.Value = imgList.Images[0];
    }
    else
    {
        e.Value = imgList.Images[1];
    }
}
```

and it solves my problem :). Thanks @Chris and @Reza